# Fileupload is not working in FireFox

Tags: extjs

I'm uploading a file with fileuploadfield.

Code snippet:

```
myUploadForm.getForm().submit({
   url: 'ref/uploadData',
   waitMsg: 'Uploading file...',

   success: function( form, action ) {
      alert('sueccess');
   },

   failure:function(form, action) {
      alert('failure');
   }    
});
```

and from backend (grails) i'm getting the response object as 
{success:true, name:'etc'}.

Here the Problem is this is working fine in chrome and IE.
But in firefox it is not working. 
It is downloading the file named as requested url method and in that file it's writing the response.

i.e, 
uploadData
{success:true,
name:'etc'}

Where as in net tab of firebug I'm able to see the proper reponse. 
This problem is only in FireFox.

Any Help would be really appreciated.

Regards
url

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try setting as below

```
 response.contenttype ="text/html" // sometimes not required.
 render ("{ success: true, result:'file has been uploaded succesfully'}" )
```

This worked for me.. give it a try.